# Can I able to unbind the public IP from the Alibaba ECS instance?

Tags: ip, cloud, alibaba-cloud, eip, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I understand that Public IP is allocated at the creation of the instance or automatically allocated by the system when I upgrade bandwidth above 0MPBS. Can I able to unbind the public IP from the ECS instance? or Is it better to use Elastic IP?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things needs to be understood,

1. If you don't select public IP it means you are accessing the instance within your Virtual Private Network(intranet). There you get 100Mbps of connection by default, also there is nothing charged for the to and fro traffic within the network.
2. You will get to use the public IP one if you want to access the instance from the public (Internet).
3. Yes, there are some benefits in terms of using the EIP(Elastic IP) like the unbinding and binding which gives a flexible management of IP addresses. But you need to analyze whether there is a need to do so?

Let me know if you have any more doubts. Thanks